# Use checkbox with conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the checkboxes are checked if the object's boolean attribute is true. Otherwise, it should be unchecked.

`<%=check_box_tag user.id, 'check_user', {:checked => user.submit, :disabled => true}%>`

`submit` is an attribute the user has. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try this `<%=check_box_tag user.id, 'check_user', :checked => user.submit == true ? true : false, {:disabled => true}%>`

Comment: It says `SyntaxError`..

Comment: I overlooked it. Can you try this `<%= check_box_tag user.id, 'check_user', user.submit, {:disabled => true} %>`

Comment: works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})

The below code should work

```
<%= check_box_tag user.id, 'check_user', user.submit, {:disabled => true} %>
```

As `submit` is a *boolean attribute*, its value can be directly passed to the `checked` to make the checkbox *checked* or *unchecked* based on its value.